# Duplicate package documentation in RStudio

Tags: r, package, rstudio

I've started creating a package through RStudio. When I start a new package (New Project -> New Directory -> R Package) the documentation for the base package is duplicated, with one help page titled 'packagename-package' and the other called 'packagename' (see image below).

[image]

Although there are two help pages visible, there is only one .Rd file in the man/ folder ('packagename-package.Rd'). When I edit this .Rd file, the information changes in both the duplicate help pages. Is this a known issue when building packages in RStudio, and is there a way to get rid of one of these duplicates?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Not really necessary.  If you look at some other packages, they have these two links as well.  For example in `help(package = "dplyr")` there is `dplyr-package` and in the D section there is `dplyr` and they are the same. I think that's just how it goes.

Comment: There's only one help page, but it's linked to from two places

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the quick responses! Just wanted to make sure it wasn't a major issue before I tried loading things in to CRAN.